# allegro y mi cpu

Tags: c++, allegro

Estoy empezando a usar allegro y al estar trabajando en un proyecto me pasaba que el proyecto no cargaba, me di cuenta de que las cosas se dibujaban de forma incompleta (estoy usando los Bitmaps de allegro) u otras veces la consola quedaba en negro al abrir el administrador de tareas me empecé a dar cuenta de que el cpu llegaba al 100%, imagino que debe de suceder porque hay algo con lo que no estoy teniendo cuidado.

Abajo adjunto todo mi codigo pero es un verdadero espagueti:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

#include <allegro.h>
#include "inicia.h"

#define maxfil 11
#define maxcolm 11

BITMAP *buffer; BITMAP *oceano; BITMAP *barcobmp; BITMAP *barco;
BITMAP *barco2; BITMAP *buqueM; BITMAP *disparoF;

BITMAP *menu;


enum direccion{ HORIZONTAL,VERTICAL }; direccion dir=HORIZONTAL; int
px=0; int py=0;


char mapa[maxfil][maxcolm]={
                    "OOOOOOOOOO",
                    "OOOOOOOOOO",
                    "OOOOOOOOOO",
                    "OO11OOOOOO",
                    "OOOOOOOOOO",
                    "OOOOOOOOOO",
                    "OOOOOOOOOO",
                    "OOOOOOOOOO",
                    "OOOOOOOOOO",
                    "OOOOOOOOOO",
                    }; void dibujarOceano() {
    int pinto=0;
    for(int fila=0;fila<maxfil-1;fila++){
        for(int columna=0;columna<maxcolm-1;columna++){
            if(mapa[fila][columna]=='O'){
                draw_sprite(buffer,oceano,columna*30,fila*30);
            }
            if(mapa[fila][columna]=='1' && pinto<1){

                draw_sprite(buffer,buqueM,columna*30,fila*30);
                pinto=+1;
            }
        }
    }



} void dibujarMenu(){ rotate_sprite(menu,buqueM,0,0,itofix(64));
rotate_sprite(menu,buqueM,30,0,itofix(64));
rotate_sprite(menu,buqueM,90,0,itofix(64));
rotate_sprite(menu,buqueM,120,0,itofix(64));
rotate_sprite(menu,buqueM,150,0,itofix(64));

//    bool salida=false; // //    while(!salida){ //       
if((mouse_x>=380&&mouse_x<=700)&&(mouse_y>=180&&mouse_y<=230)){ //    
blit(fondo1,buffer,0,0,0,0,800,530); //            if(mouse_b & 1){ //
Vista=JUGAR; //                salida=true; //            } //       
}else if((mouse_x>380&&mouse_x<=717)&&(mouse_y>=260&&mouse_y<=320)){
//            blit(fondo2,buffer,0,0,0,0,800,530); //           
if(mouse_b & 1){ // //                salida=true; //            } // 
} //        else
if((mouse_x>325&&mouse_x<=760)&&(mouse_y>=360&&mouse_y<=420)){ //     
blit(fondo3,buffer,0,0,0,0,800,530); //            if(mouse_b & 1){ //
Vista=ACERCA; //                salida=true; //            } //       
} //        else
if((mouse_x>490&&mouse_x<=650)&&(mouse_y>=460&&mouse_y<=530)){ //     
blit(fondo4,buffer,0,0,0,0,800,530); //            if(mouse_b & 1){ //
Vista=MANUAL; //                salida=true; //            } //       
} //        else{ //            blit(fondo,buffer,0,0,0,0,800,530); //
} //        masked_blit(cursor,buffer,0,0,mouse_x,mouse_y,13,22); //  
blit(buffer,screen,0,0,0,0,800,530); //    } // //    run();
                }

void dibujarBarco(){
    switch(dir){
        case HORIZONTAL:
        draw_sprite(buffer,barco,px*30,py*30);
        break;
        case VERTICAL:
        rotate_sprite(buffer,barco,(px*30)-15,(py*30)+15, itofix(64));
        break;
    } }

void pantalla(){
    blit(menu,screen,0,0,(SCREEN_W-200),(SCREEN_H-150),300,300); } int main () {
    inicia_allegro(640,640);
    inicia_audio(70,70);

    install_mouse();

    buffer = create_bitmap(SCREEN_W,SCREEN_H);

    menu=create_bitmap(150,150);

    oceano=load_bitmap("agua.bmp",NULL);

    barco=load_bitmap("buqueMinero.bmp",NULL);

    barco=load_bitmap("submarino.bmp",NULL);

    buqueM=load_bitmap("buqueMinero.bmp",NULL);

    bool termino=false;
    while(!termino){
            px=(mouse_x/30);
            py=(mouse_y/30);
            if(px>=9){px=8;}
            if(py>=9){py=8;}
            if(key[KEY_RIGHT]){
                    if(mapa[py/30][(px+30)/30]!='x' && (px+30)/30<9){
                    dir=HORIZONTAL;
                    }
            }
            if(key[KEY_LEFT]){
                if(mapa[(py+30)/30][(px)/30]!='x' && (px+30)/30<9){
                    dir=VERTICAL;
                    }
            }
            clear(buffer);

            dibujarMenu();

            pantalla();

    }
            rest(70);

    }
```

Comment: El código es espagueti porque tu quieres que sea así. No cuesta tanto tabular el código correctamente y darle un poco de sentido para que sea sencillo de seguir

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/221423/is-there-any-reason-to-limit-my-fps